# Поочередная смена картинок

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Представьте себе область (ячейка таблицы), в которой нужно сделать, несколько картинок, которые будут поочередно меняться автоматически, и пару кнопочек, при нажатии на которые, можно посмотреть на одну из них. Такую штуку не однократно видел в интернете, скажем на сайте самсунга есть.

1. Как это правильно называется?
2. Есть ли где готовый элемент, который можно посмотреть, и скопировать? Ну, или подскажите код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В интернете много пример таких галерей. Ищутся по запросу JavaScript(jquery) галерея. Вот тебе несколько примеров:

- [jCarousel - Examples](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples)
- [20 AJAX галерей на jQuery](http://shublog.ru/ajax/jquery/20-ajax-galerejj-na-jquery/)
- [Лучшие jQuery галереи и слайдеры](http://www.peaxl.ru/coding/luchshie-jquery-galerei-i-slajdery/)

Answer (score 2):

Пользуюсь этим: [jQuery Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/autoscroll.html). Хороший плагин.